# Annoying Loading Image (HTML/CSS)

Tags: html, css, icons, background-image, loading

I have a website with many thumbnails. The thumbnails are defined like this:

```
<li>
    <a href='Pic/$gal/sized/$file'>
        <img src='Pic/$gal/thumb/$file' alt=''></img>
    </a>
</li>
```

and the CSS that effects them:

Global img-CSS:

```
img {
    display: block; 
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0; 
    border: none; 
    background: url('../images/load.gif') no-repeat center;
}
```

Special css code for the thumbnails:

```
.gallery ul li img {    
    width: 174px;
    height: 174px;
    padding: 4px;   
    border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;      
}
```

I want to use the background-image as a loading-icon. But as you can see on the following picture, there always is an ugly icon on the left-top of the thumbnail until the picture is completely loaded. I tried to use an background-image as large as the thumbnail itself, so the ugly icon would be overlaped. But this does not work.

http://s7.directupload.net/images/130225/v3l3hkfs.png

Do you have any idea, how I can remove this icon?

Regards,
Oliver

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a blank .png or .gif as the image source and then change the src once the image is loaded.

EDIT:
A good way to store the original src is with a data attribute:

```
<img data-src='Pic/$gal/thumb/$file' src='blank.png' alt='' />
```

Answer (score 3):

Those are browser generated so you cant get rid of them and the icon will depend on the browser used. In order to not have them show you would need to involve javascript to render the images off canvas or do some kind of preloading.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much slamborne!

I created a 1px times 1px transparent blank.png and then I modifed my HTML Tag:

```
echo "<li><a rel='gallery_group' href='Pic/$gal/sized/$file'><img data-src='Pic/$gal/thumb/$file' src='images/blank.png' alt=''></img></a></li> ";
```

As you can see, the blank.png is the image source. The blank.png is loaded very quickly, because it is a very tiny picture. My next step was to make sure, that the real image is loaded after the page is loaded.

To do so, I wrote a simple javascript function, that changes all "src" attributes of images to the value of "data-src" attributes:

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
function neueSrc () {
    var all = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
    for (var i=0, max=all.length; i < max; i++) {   
        all[i].src = all[i].getAttribute('data-src');
    }
}
</script>
```

This function is executed in the body-tag:

```
<body onload="neueSrc()">
```

That is exactly what I wanted! Thank you very much for you quick responses and usefull help.

Comment: You're welcome. I know that this isn't for a background image but I'm just throwing this out there because it was a hard issue to track down. I've had problems in the past using 1x1 px images as background images so I've gotten into the habit of using 2x2 px images as the smallest size.